# /bin/bash: npm: command not found (docker container)

Tags: docker, npm, nvm

I have build a docker image with [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

```
FROM ubuntu:19.10

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean all


RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    bash-completion

ARG NODE_VERSION='12.0.0'
ARG NVM_DIR=/root
ARG NVM_VERSION='v0.35.3'

RUN curl -o- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/$NVM_VERSION/install.sh" | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION

ENV TERM=xterm
```

Now I am trying to test that I can start a container and run `npm`:

```
docker run my-npm-image /bin/bash -c  "npm --version"
```

but that gives:

```
/bin/bash: npm: command not found
```

If I instead do:

```
docker run -it my-npm-image /bin/bash
root@laptop:/# npm --version
6.9.0
```

It works. So `npm` is installed in the image but I cannot run it without *entering* the container first.

Notice running other commands works fine using the above approach:

```
docker run my-npm-image /bin/bash -c  "git --version"
git version 2.20.1
```

Any ideas whats brooken with `npm` installed with `nvm` in the above dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is not aware of `npm` location because if i set `PATH` explicitly, it works for me.

```
$ docker run --rm my-npm-image /bin/bash -c "PATH=/root/versions/node/v12.0.0/bin;$PATH npm --version"
6.9.0
```

To set `npm` path, try adding the following to your Dockerfile:

```
...
...
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

ENV TERM=xterm
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/aacf14c29b3f01d6900d13137b21db3a

Comment: Hm and there is no way to fix this in the dockerfile so I don't have to do this each time I run a container from the image?

Comment: @u123: Did you try using the two `ENV` suggested above in my updated answer? It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can figure that out using the `docker exec`

```
docker exec -it <container-Id> npm --version
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

It's also works the way you mentioned, it might depend on the image you are using or a miss configuration

```
 docker run -it node:12  /bin/bash -c  "npm --version"
 6.14.4
```

Comment: But that assumes the container is already running, is it not possible to just run a container and send/run a command and then shutdown?

Comment: No, it should be working !, it's related to the nvm installation @u123

Comment: Well thats a public node image you are running, I am trying to run an image from my own dockerfile where I try to install node through nvm and with that image it does not work, possibly because I am doing something wrong in my docker file - which is why I have posted this question.

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong, it's the way nvm work as nvm not a service it register in the .bashrc file it's executable file location, i faced this problem before trying to make different users in same machine using nvm, If you normally use node installation it's supposed to be working, I'm searching for the article that talk about this nvm issue once i find it i will post it here

Comment: Ok but just make clear its the specific image/dockerfile/nvm/npm I provided in the post I am having the problem with not node in general that works just fine